# CAS server login

Tags: php, linux, cas

I have follwowing code on HRM application

```
include_once('CAS.php');

phpCAS::setDebug();

phpCAS::client(CAS_VERSION_2_0, "122.243.242.43", 443, 'cas',false);

phpCAS::setNoCasServerValidation();

phpCAS::forceAuthentication();

$userName = phpCAS::getUser();
```

If i commented all the cas code and then hard code the value as  `$userName = "temp"` its working. when try to get the user name from cas server as   `$userName = phpCAS::getUser();` not working even i cant print  `$userName` display nothing.

regards
roshan

Comment: try adding 

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", true);

at the top of the page and see if you can see the errors.

Comment: did you get any extra warnings/error that you can show us so we can help you? Or did you manage to solve this yourself after displaying all the error/warning message?

Comment: no paan im in non ending redirect loop how to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
phpCAS::client(CAS_VERSION_2_0, "122.243.242.43", 443, 'cas',false);
```

remove the false arg form the above statment then ok

Answer (score 1):

Whatever code is in your ip address in your `phpcas::cas` call is the issue, make sure its setting valid variables that the cas client can use or post the code

Comment: As roshan said below , only use the false arg at the end if you are setting sessions prior to calling phpcas, if you want phpcas to handle sessions, remove